# Can I tell Lightroom to set export filenames to the Title if there is one or Original Filename when there isn't?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, lightroom-3

At the moment, when I export an image from Lightroom, I simply use the original image filename (with new extension).

What I would like to do, if I have applied a Title, is to use that as the export filename instead.

I do not title all my images, and using both title and filename together is not what I want.

Is there a way to only use Title when it has a value?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is any conditional operator to allow you to say "if title is non-blank use that, otherwise use filename".

Only two choices I can think of.

Best is to create smart collections: one with images that have titles, one without.  Then do two exports on each collection, using {Title} on one and {Original Filename} on the other.

The other choice would be to somehow set all blank titles to the original filename (on import perhaps).  Then export is easy, just use {Title} and of course rename the title for those you want to have a proper title.  I don't think that's a good choice, to use Title for something it's really not.  But it simplifies export and you don't have to use smart collections.

Comment: I'm looking for a general solution (not a specific scenario), plus I don't want duplicates of every export presets for each option, so doing different exports isn't suitable.

Setting title to filename is definitely a no go - images without titles must not have a value in the title field.

If there's no native solution I guess this means I'll need to look for if there's a plugin that can do it.